# Creating two table of contents with different depths in R Markdown

Tags: r-markdown, tableofcontents

I created my lecture notes in pdf format using RMarkdown but it has many subheaders. Because of this, I want to create two different table of contents: first table of contents with 1 depth, then table of contents in 4 depth respectively.

Adding both `toc_depth: 1` and `toc_depth: 4` did not work.

My YAML header:

```
---
title: "Lecture Notes"
author: "x"
output:
  pdf_document:
    highlight: tango 
    toc: true 
    toc_depth: 4 #depth table of contents
    number_sections: true
documentclass: article
classoption: a4paper
fontsize: 12pt 
geometry: "right=1cm, left=1cm, top=1cm, bottom=3cm"
---
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, I don't believe two Table of Contents is possible. One thing you can try is if you don't want a certain heading numbered, you can do

```
## Including Plots {-}
```

Which heads it has a header, but doesn't number it in the TOC. Here is the two output differences

without `{-}`
[image]

with `{-}`
[image]

These can be used in places like the Preface, about the authors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect solution (maybe some with more knowledge could automate this).

The solution works if the intermediate latex file is kept and a short table of contents is manually added using the [shorttoc](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/shorttoc/) package.

Adding shortdoc:

```
...
\documentclass[
]{book}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
...
```

And than adding it between title and TOC:

```
\shorttableofcontents{〈title 〉}{〈depth 〉}
```